# mysql with common table expression query

Tags: mysql

i am learning about [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), and i have a question about how the where condition on the union query works with recursive common table expressions.

if i make a dates cte with

```
WITH RECURSIVE datesCte AS
(
  SELECT 1 id, date('2010-01-01') as ymd, 2010 year, 1 month, 1 quarter 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id+1,@d:=date_add(ymd,interval 1 month), year(@d),month(@d), quarter(@d)  from datesCte where ymd < '2011-01-01'
)
select  * FROM datesCte
```

the last line of the output has the date 2011-01-01

i would expect the last row to be 2010-12-01,
what is the reason for observed output?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9phZ7EpRUS4FNRBZRdSYZa/146

Comment: Don't use user defined variables.  Give the date column in the first select an alias, then add to it in the second select, just like you are doing with id.  And there's no need to have the separate year/month/quarter columns?

Comment: But to answer your question, your where condition will select the 20101201 row and add to it.  Where constrains what is selected, not what the select returns.